# chrome extension: where/how to host user-contributed data?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, hosting

**question:**

how/where to send HTML objects from individual users to common (accessible) database? how/where to host?

**context:**

In a browser game, the states of many in-game objects constantly change. These states are useful to know, and you can go check the objects to see their states in plain HTML, but it is costly, in terms of time and in-game resources.

Many players cooperate, each checking various objects and reporting their findings, but there is a lot of overhead (typing) involved, and it is generally difficult to organize.

I want to write code that will eliminate the overhead AND organize the data. It will gather HTML data from individual users, as they encounter in-game objects, and send the latest state of each object to a common database, where it will be time-stamped and organized, available for participating user to query/view.

But where/how can I store such a database? Is there a utility already built into chrome extensions, for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You have to host external servers yourself. For example in Google Compute Engine or pre-made services. The only similar facility that Chrome has is storage.sync but its meant for small data and only syncs between browsers with the same chrome users.